# Facebook Group Search post without comments

Tags: facebook

Hi,

As title, in my facebook group, I need to retrieve only post without comments.

I see the search box and notice that searching something will give an url with

```
`?query=Word%20Search`
```

and maybe there is a way to search post without comments by url.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You must use the Graph API to retrieve data from Facebook. There is example code how to get the group feed in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group/feed#read

You can´t filter by posts without comments, you need to do the filtering on your own after getting the posts.

Comment: Thanks for reply @luschn. I'm studying a totally new world for me,
but I've some problems. I can retrieve all comments (i use graph explorer). Now that I have group feed i'm trying to filter post, by comments total count.
'feed?fields=posts(comments.limit(0))' 
is what i come to after lot of study. But I doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: as i said, you have to do the filtering on your own after getting the posts. you can try this though, to make it easier: feed?fields=comments.summary(true)

Comment: Ok now I understand, that can't be done with graph api. With that field I can search for "total_count": 0 and I have to find a way to retrieve the post id corresponding to that field. Thanks again!